# Error itms-90086 missing 64-bit support Xcode 7.3 (Unity IL2CPP Build)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, 64-bit, il2cpp

The report of the other questions and answers already tried this and that.

This is my build setting:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN4Wb.png]

(Of course, the project setting is also set standard architecture. )

However, the error itms-90086 will still occur.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think in Unity you have specified:

Player Settings > Other Settings > Architecture to arm7 while it has to be set to Universal.

Edit:
Also, to make development builds easier set "Build Active Architecture Only" for Debug (and Debug only!) to YES. Then go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme and set Build Configuration to Debug. This way you'll only build arm7 OR arm64 when testing instead of arm7 AND arm64 which takes around x1.5 more time to compile in xCode.